# Regular expressions, how to replace the first letter when followed by digits

Tags: regex, r

I have a dataframe in which I want to transform a variable depending on its value.

How to get the positions of the rows containing a value beginning with 'B+digits' and then replace it by 'BLA+the same digits'?

More precisly, here is an example of replacement I want to do: 'B92MEL-word2' by 'BLAB92'.

I have tried:

```
  grep("^B[[:digit:]]*", dataset$variable)
```

It finds values like 'B+digits' but also finds values I do not want:

```
  BLA192/MEL poword2
  BLA25879 - blabla
```

Comment: I'd suggest you''ll look into `?rep` before using it.

Comment: what would be the expected output?

Comment: I want on my output the numbers of rows containing strings beginning  with 'B+digits'.

Comment: sorry the function is 'grep' and not 'rep'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
sub('^(B\\d+).*', 'BLA\\1', str1)
#[1] "BLA192/MEL poword2" "BLA25879 - blabla"  "BLAB92"
```

#### Update

```
 sub('^B(\\d+).*', 'BLA\\1', str1)
 #[1] "BLA192/MEL poword2" "BLA25879 - blabla"  "BLA92"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c('BLA192/MEL poword2', 'BLA25879 - blabla', 'B92MEL-word2')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I want something like "BLA92" instead of BLAB92", how to do this?

Comment: @SparkUser Updated the post Please check.

Comment: Thank you, but how to modify directly my dataframe now? Because this returns only a vector modified... (in my case str1 is data$variable)

Comment: @SparkUser, Try `data$variable <- sub('^B(\\d+).*', 'BLA\\1', data$variable)`